# Styled Components: How to target ad apply css to text inside div

Tags: css, styled-components

I've a component called `StyledBody` which is a styled `div`:

```
const StyledBody = styled.div`
   padding: 8px 0;
   & ::content {
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 0.825rem;
      line-height: 1.2rem;
      text-align: justify;
   }
`;

export { StyledBody };
```

This `div` contains a text which has this format:

```
<div> Welcome to stack overflow </div>
```

I've used `::content` pseudo-class but it does not have any impact. How can I styled the text inside the div without adding `p` or `span`?

Comment: Why would you need `::content` in this case? Why not just apply the styles to the `div`?

Comment: You can use those styles directly on div and they'll have same effect. If you're seeing something different, then can you create a reproducible example ?